# Curl taking too long to send https request using command line

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have implemented one shall script which send an https request to proxy with authorization header using GET request.

Here is my command :

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" -X GET -H "Authorization: 123456:admin05" "https://www.mywebpage/api/request/india/?ID=123456&Number=9456123789&Code=01"
```

It takes around 12 second to wait and then sending request to proxy and revert back with some code like 200,400,500 etc..

Is it possible to reduce time and make it faster using CURL ?

Please advice me for such a case.

Thanks.

Comment: No curl can't make the server respond quicker.

Comment: Buts it takes 10 to 12 sec which is not at all acceptable, right ?

Comment: It's not curl thats slow...

Comment: so which part of request its do slow my request ?

Comment: Use `--trace-time` or perhaps even just strace to figure that out!

Comment: I tried with --trace-time but when i do enter of the above command, it will take around 8 second to send a request. then start showing info for verbose. how can i reduce it ?

Comment: Any-other thoughts for me ?

Answer (score 1):

Use option `-v` or `--verbose` along with `--trace-time`

It gives details of actions begin taken along with timings.

Includes DNS resolution, SSL handshake, etc. Line starting with '>' means header/body being sent, '<' means being received.

Based on difference between operation sequence - you can decipher whether server is taking time to respond (time between request and response) or network latency or bandwidth(response taking) time.

Comment: I do execute date command and execute curl command in terminal and see the execution start time and execute command time. its taking too much time to start the request. http://pastebin.com/UVnv0vAR

Comment: use date;<your-curl-command>. there won't be 12 seconds gap. you are using two different commands - copy-pasting/typing command is also taking time out of 12 second. Figure out yourself.

Comment: Nope i am not doing copy-paste OR typing, i just press up arraow to execute command quickly, it hardly takes 1 sec to execute it. Please help.Also is it possible its due to https certificate ?